# Google autocomplete json for nearby places

Tags: ios, google-maps, autocomplete, maps, google-places-api

I want to use autocomplete json for nearby places using google maps in iphone application.I have created the API key for that, and used in url:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=mumbai&radius=5020&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyB2jO4ZrvpOIg9uLTsDdy_jjpcjuWY34qA
```

But result I am getting is that this IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 59.182.167.204, with empty referrer.

Answer (score 0):

Your API key is not valid...
it seems you using `Server-key` or `Browser-key`
You need to use `iOS-key` and your app Bundle ID `com.exemple.YourApp`.